What factors are most important when deciding the standard behaviour of a digital UI component with an analog origin?
When standards bodies like the W3C decide on how a user interface element should look and behave - particularly when the element is a modern interpretation of something that used to be common in the physical world - which factors do they consider to be most important?
For example, on the question of Why is it impossible to deselect HTML "radio" inputs?, many of the answers point to the fact that web radio buttons originated from desktop OS radio buttons, which originated from the chunky buttons on handheld radios. So the way people used to operate those is a factor in how they should operate on the web today. But there must have been many other considerations.
So some of the factors I can think of are:

What the element used to look like in the physical world and how it was designed
How most people used to operate it back then (or how they remember using it)
What modernisations are needed to make it fully accessible
What other elements fulfil a similar purpose (e.g. checkboxes), and how to keep them distinct
If it needs to perform multiple functions (in the case of radio buttons: only allow one option to be selected, and prevent deselecting a selected option)
What a modern group of (focus group) individuals demonstrate as their understanding of it

To summarise, which of these factors would standards bodies consider most important when deciding if a radio button, for example, should be "deselectable"?

Welcome to the site! "But there must have been many other considerations" - why do you think that?

@virtualnobi Well I have a lot of respect for those people. If you look at the W3C docs on inputs and the radio button specifically, it's very comprehensive, so lots of thought and discussion (and perhaps research) must have gone into the decisions.

It would be hard to say which are the most important (since they didn't state this explicitly), and I suspect it would also be context sensitive in some way. I am not sure this is a question that has a definitive answer.
